# ParseXamlException Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I receive an error in my Windows Phone 8.1 app:

**the text associated with this error code could not be found (ParseXamlException)**

Line 28 Col 28

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="ConnectorX_UniversalApp.UI.LoginUserControl"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:local="using:ConnectorX_UniversalApp.CommonUI">

    <!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="ms-appx:///Assets/CustomUI/background.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock x:Uid="BuisnessConnectorTextBlock" Margin="5,15,0,0" FontSize="25" x:Name="BuisnessConnectorTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

Xaml is valid. This error appears after I clone and run project on another laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app crashes when it tries to create the TextBlock.
Have you made sure there is a resource named "BuisnessConnectorTextBlock" in your .resw file?

The xaml parser will try to find the specified resource and apply its properties to the TextBlock. If the resource doesn't exist the parser will throw an exception. Also if the resource has any properties that don't fit a TextBlock you will get an exception too.

(It looks to me like a typo it should be "BusinessConnectorTextBlock")

Comment: the answer is almost there - I have no resource for en-EN (have for de-DE) but it was default language in appxmanifest. Seems like after cloning project to another laptop, configurations were reseted.